# Is it possible to log the response data in nginx access log?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to print the response data for development/debugging purposes. I couldn't find a similar question or any info on this. If you do, please add a comment.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body

Comment: No. That is the request body but I want to spit out the response body. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `body_filter_by_lua` to assign request body to a nginx variable, here is an example:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format log_req_resp '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time req_body:"$request_body" resp_body:"$resp_body"';

    server {
        listen 8082;
        access_log logs/access.log log_req_resp;

        lua_need_request_body on;

        set $resp_body "";
        body_filter_by_lua '
            local resp_body = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], 1, 1000)
            ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. resp_body
            if ngx.arg[2] then
                ngx.var.resp_body = ngx.ctx.buffered
            end
        ';

        location / {
            echo "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code , we seem to be putting the first 1000 bytes from the response chunk and putting into resp_body i.e. in this line "resp_body = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], 1, 1000)". Is there a specific reason for this to be 1000.

Comment: In my case its not giving me response body but its giving me the path of log like this "resp_body:""access_log/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.logupstreamlog"

Can you please suggest what's wrong?

Comment: `body_filter_by_lua_block { ngx.var.resp_body = (ngx.var.resp_body or "") .. ngx.arg[1] }` is also possible

Answer (score 3):

use ngx_lua module

like this

```
body_filter_by_lua 'ngx.log(ngx.CRIT,ngx.arg[1])';
```

in the right `location`

Comment: I think I'd prefer to use `ngx.DEBUG`. CRIT might get printed to the console, emailed to the whole sysadmin team, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501814/can-i-echo-a-request-header-value-as-the-response-body-with-vanilla-nginx), and I think the [echo module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule) can also do it.

Comment: The echo module and the example provided talk about logging the request headers/body but I want to log the response body. Thanks petermolanar.