# Log response body in nginx

Tags: nginx, logging, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

How do you log the **response body** (not request body) in nginx? I could not find such a variable in any of the modules (only the [request body](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_body)).

We are using nginx as a reverse proxy/loadbalancer and would like to parse our API requests & responses from nginx logs.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know anything like mod_security for Apache, that allows such type of logging. Maybe a 3Party Module?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/479123 might answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could log the headers using [$upstream_http_HEADER](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#.24upstream_http_.24HEADER). Doesn't seem like there is a variable for the response body though but I'm not surprised - this part would be optimized.