# log complete response data in string format in nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to log complete response in nginx. I tried below approach suggested in other threads([Is it possible to log the response data in nginx access log?](https://serverfault.com/questions/361556/is-it-possible-to-log-the-response-data-in-nginx-access-log))
but its logging the response in byte format which is not human readable. I needs the complete response in String human readable format.
Any ideas highly appreciated.

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format log_req_resp '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time req_body:"$request_body" resp_body:"$resp_body"';
    server {
        listen 8082;
        access_log logs/access.log log_req_resp;
        lua_need_request_body on;
        set $resp_body "";
        body_filter_by_lua '
            local resp_body = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], 1, 1000)
            ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. resp_body
            if ngx.arg[2] then
                ngx.var.resp_body = ngx.ctx.buffered
            end
        ';
        location / {
            echo "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible with log module. It's hardcoded into the module to escape everything except ascii symbols. But you could try to do it with Lua.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I am using reverse proxy to other domain. Could you please provide some more details on Lua approach to achieve this. Won't there be any performance impact on converting the bytes to string thru lua?

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.open